# What flavor of CRC-CCITT?

Tags: crc, crc16

Can anyone tell what flavor CRC-CCITT is [implemented in this code](http://www.drdobbs.com/implementing-the-ccitt-cyclical-redundan/199904926)?

When I use it to compute a CRC over "123456789", I get 0x6E90.  But it doesn't match any of the CRCs here: https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

But it does exhibit the property of a CRC where including the CRC in the data that is CRC'd results in a known constant value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code shows a right shifting CRC16 based on 0x11021, which when bit reversed and shifted right 1 bit becomes 0x8408. This is a variation of CRC-CCITT (Kermit), but unlike Kermit, it starts with CRC = 0xFFFF (Kermit starts with CRC = 0x0000), and ones complement the CRC at the end, so it won't match any of the CRCs shown at the lammertbies web site. You can verify that it's similar to Kermit by going to the lammertbies web site, switching to hex mode and entering a single byte 80, which will result in 0x0884, which is a byte swapped 0x8408 due to little endian.

If it wasn't for the ones complement at the end, then appending a CRC to data and recalculating a CRC for the data + CRC would return a CRC of 0x0000, for any of the normal CRC methods. With the post ones complement, you get a constant depending on which CRC implementation is used, in this case 0x470F (byte swapped again due to little endian).

To test this, go to the lammertbies web site, prefix the string with hex 21 F3, which will cause the Kermit CRC to be 0xFFFF after processing the 21 F3. Switch to hex input and enter the string:

```
21F3313233343536373839
```

this will result in the Kermit CRC returning

```
0x916F
```

which when one's complemented is

```
0x6e90
```

You can change the Dr Dobb's example code to match Kermit with these changes:

```
    crc = 0;     /* instead of crc = 0xffff; */
    /* ... */
    /* crc = ~crc;  comment out this line    */
```